# Return themed node via AJAX / AHAH

Tags: 7, nodes, ajax

Is there a way to get a fully themed node given the node id or path alias so that I can render it via AJAX / AHAH?

Answer (score 2):

Create a menu hook with the path `"[themed_node/%node]"`.

Within the function returning the the output for the menu hook use

```
return theme_node($node);
```

And then make an ajax call to "themed_node/nodeid" whenever you need the themed node.

Hope that should work.

Comment: Also if only want to return the themed node and not the complete site you can just print the output instead of return it, in that way only will be returned the node itself and not the complete site.